# Why Two Equal Resistors Cut Voltage in Half?

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

I've been reading several books on electronics, one of them called *"Electronics All-In-One  For Dummies - D. Lowe (Wiley, 2012) BBS"*. It states that if two resistors of the same value, no matter the values, are in series, the initial voltage from the battery will be cut in half. In other words as long as two resistors have the same value the voltage will be cut in half, this sounds wrong, how could the values of the resistors not matter?

Comment: I actually think it would have been better _not_ to edit your sample calculation out of the question. Even though the calculation wasn't correct, it would give us some insight as to why exactly you're not able to figure it out, and it does show that at least you tried something.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's actually draw a schematic:

[image]

Here, I've drawn two resistors, R1 and R2, in series and connected to a battery.

The key point about resistors (or any other 2-terminal elements) *in series* is that the current through them is the same. If there's current flowing through R1, there's no other place for it to go at node "B" than through R2, so the current through R2 must be equal to the current through R1. (this is just a simple statement of *Kirchoff's Current Law*)

Now, Ohm's Law tells us what's the voltage across a resistor, depending on its current:

$$V=IR$$

For the first resistor we'd have,

$$V(R_1)=I(R_1)\times{}R_1$$

and for the second resistor,

$$V(R_2)=I(R_2)\times{}R_2$$.

But, in your problem, the values of R1 and R2 are equal, R1 = R2. Let's just call that value *R*.

And since the current through the two resistors is equal, we'll just call that current *I*.

Now, we get $V(R_1)=V(R_2)=I\times{}R$, which we can just call $V(R)$.

This already shows that the voltage is "evenly split" between the two resistors. Since the voltage across the two resistors is equal, the voltage at "B" must be exactly half-way between the voltages at "C" and "A".

Note: We didn't even have to mention the battery or its voltage to get this result. Simply because the two resistors are equal, and there's nowhere for current to go at node "B", we know that the voltage between A and C is split equally between the two resistors.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, the voltage drop over both resisters must equal the voltage of the battery, otherwise there would be a voltage difference at a single 'node' in the circuit.  If the resistors have the same resistance, than it makes sense that the voltage drop over each resister must be the same.

Smaller resistors would simply allow more current to flow through, but the voltage drop must be the same (totally to the voltage of the battery).

Comment: I think then, that one resistor drops 5%, then the other drops 5% from the remaining 95% allowed from the first resistor. Is this it?

Comment: It doesn't make since if each resistor only drops by 5%.  With a 100v battery, each resistor would then only drop 5v with a total of 10v.  Then after the resistors, you would still have 90v unaccounted for when you get back to the battery.  The percentage drop over all resisters must be 100% (in series this would just be added).

Comment: This video may help some https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOR0R9BXoHc

Answer (score 2):

> It states that if two resistors of the same value, no matter the
>   values, are in series, the initial voltage from the battery will be
>   cut in half.

It is true is that the voltage *across* each resistor is equal to one-half the voltage across the battery.

This is quite easy to derive.  Since the two resistors are series connected, the series current depends on the *sum* of the two resistances.  Denoting that resistance $R$, the series current is

$$I = \frac{V_{BAT}}{R + R} =  \frac{V_{BAT}}{2R}$$

See that the greater the value $R$, the less the current $I$.

Now, by Ohm's law, the voltage across either resistor is given by the product of the series current and the resistance:

$$V_R = IR = \frac{V_{BAT}}{2R}R = \frac{V_{BAT}}{2}$$

So, in this special case, the $R$ in the numerator and denominator cancel such that this is *independent* of the resistance $R$.

More generally, if the two resistors have *different* resistances, the series current is

$$I = \frac{V_{BAT}}{R_1 + R_2}$$

and then

$$V_{R1} = IR_1 = \frac{V_{BAT}}{R_1 + R_2}R_1 = V_{BAT}\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}$$

$$V_{R2} = IR_2 = \frac{V_{BAT}}{R_1 + R_2}R_2 = V_{BAT}\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}$$

This is called *[voltage division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider#Resistive_divider)* - the battery voltage divides across the resistors proportionally.

Answer (score 1):

Each resistor in series will always carry the same current as the others. Since the current through a series circuit is halved when the resistance is doubled (Ohms law), so the voltage across each resistor must be halved. Similarly, three equal resistors will 'split' the total voltage across them into thirds.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage drops completely across the two resistors. Being them equal, and being the drop linear with the resistance, each of them is responsible for the drop of half the whole voltage.

Comment: that doesn't really answer my question. Why is it that it doesn't matter the value of the two resistors and as long as they have equal value the voltage will be cut in half?

Comment: I think this is precisely what I've tried to express. Apologies if I haven't succeeded

Answer (score 0):

What it does not mean: It does NOT mean  that you have a circuit and by putting two resistors you have your voltage dropped in half. It only means that the voltage drop for each resistor when there is  no other thing in the circuit (not even an internal resistance within the battery) will be half of the voltage drop (and half the current) than you would for only one resistor (and no other thing in the circuit).

To understand why is so for 1 versus 2 resistors, you can see the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

They 'cut the voltage in half' because the equal resistance values makes their voltage drop equivalent.

In the circuit in which you describe, the effective voltage at the end is ground ($0\ V$, 0%) and at the source is battery voltage ($x\ V$, 100%). Each resistor of equivalent resistence in series will drop an equal percentage; so two resistors would each drop 50%, resulting in $x/2\ V$

Note that three equal resistors would cut it in equal thirds ($x/3\ V$, 33%).

Thus, in this context, it does not matter what value the resistors have so long as there are two of them in series and the values are roughly equivalent.

What you're describing is known as a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider), this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) details it, in the specific case where $Z_1 = Z_2$.

Comment: that's where I'm confused because a 3k resistor will not drop the same percentage of voltage as a 10k resistor. So, if a 3k resistor drops 15% of the voltage just adding another one of the same value will make it 30%, not 50%.

Comment: @reddead - If the circuit only has 1 battery and 1 resister, the voltage drop over the resister must be 100% of the battery's voltage; it doesn't matter what the resistance or voltage are.

Comment: Now you're changing this, but you have to evaluate percentage OF TOTAL. Two 3k resistors in series = 6k ohms, each taking 3k/6k = 50%. A 3k and a 10k resistor in series = 13k ohms, the 3k taking 3k/13k = 23% and the 10k taking 10k/13k = 77%.

Comment: @Cemafor what??? How does a 3k resistor resist ALL voltage on a 200 volt battery?

Comment: If you have a 10k and a 3k, then add another 3k, the total is now 16k, so the 10k now drops 62%, and each 3k drops 19%. The equivalent values resistors still drop an equivalent amount of voltage.

Comment: @Ehryk so one resistor has its regular value, but suddenly, when coupled when another of the same value their resistance value increases? Very confusing, alone they behave one way, coupled with a twin they behave in another.

Comment: @reddead - Resistors resist current, not voltage. Given that I=V/R (Ohm's law), with your scenario, 200volts/3000ohms = .067amps; so as long as the resistor is rated for at least .067 amps, everything is fine.  If you measure the voltage across the battery, it will be the same as across the resister.

Comment: @reddead that is correct. When twin same valued resistors are put in series, they double the total resistance, when in parallel they half it. The resistors themselves maintain the same value. Similarly, when you put two 'twin' batteries together their voltage adds.